# How can I execute script with xargs after find command

Tags: unix

```
find . -name "recovery_script" | xargs
```

I try to execute but it only prints it. How can I run it parallel ?

Comment: This is most likely a duplicate; have you tried searching for `xargs parallel`?

Comment: it doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

```
find . -name "recovery_script" | xargs -n1 -P8 sh
```

for 8 processes in parallel.
Provided there are at least 8 places where "recovery_script" can be found.

The `-n1` argument is necessary to feed one argument at a time to `sh`. Otherwise, `xargs` will feed a reasonable number of arguments all at once to `sh`, meaning it's trying to execute something like

```
sh dir1/recovery_script dir2/recovery_script dir3/recovery_script ...
```

instead of

```
sh dir1/recovery_script
sh dir2/recovery_script
sh dir3/recovery_script
...
```

in parallel.

Bonus: your command can be longer than just a single command, including options. I often use `nice` to allow other processes to still continue without problems:

```
find . -name "recovery_script" | xargs -n1 -P8 nice -n19
```

where `-n19` is an option to `nice`, not to `xargs`.

(Aside: if you ever use wildcards for `-name` in `find`, use the `-print0` option to `find`, and the `-0` option to `xargs`: that separates output and input by the null character, instead of whitespace (since the latter may be part of the filename). Since you search for the full name here, that is not a problem.)

---

From the `xargs` manual page:

> SYNOPSIS: `xargs` ... [command [initial-arguments]]

and

> ... and executes the command (default is /bin/echo) one or more times with any initial-arguments followed by items read from standard input.

The default behaviour is thus to echo whatever arguments you give to `xargs`. Providing a command like `sh` (perhaps depending on what executable you're trying to run) then works.

Comment: it doesn't run all script simultaneously

Comment: @Alex how long does a single recovery script run? And how many recovery scripts are there (that is, the output of `find`).

Comment: the script run a few minutes and there are ten scripts. I run it from unix 128bit

Comment: Can you give me full example ?

Comment: @Alex that is at the top of the answer. What are you missing?

Answer (score 1):

This solution is not using xargs but a simple bash script. Maybe it can help:

```
#!/bin/sh

for i in $(find -name recovery_script)
do
    {
       echo "Started $i"
       $i
       echo "Ended $i"
    } &
done
wait
```